# Use utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity to select distinct rows using Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, duplication

I have a table with log messages that many times contain repeated information with slightly different values. 
For example:

```
Unable to make thread 19043 a realtime process
Unable to make thread 20763 a realtime process
Unable to make thread 22179 a realtime process
FEED_XYZ Secondary Instrument Lines not configured
FEED_ZZZ Secondary Instrument Lines not configured
(...)
```

I'd like to have just one line from each group above:

```
Unable to make thread 19043 a realtime process
FEED_XYZ Secondary Instrument Lines not configured
```

Is there a way to use a select query to retrieve distinct rows with `utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity`?

Something like:

```
select log_message
from logs_table
where "utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity between rows < 80"
```

I know that I can make a pipelined function or some other PL/SQL routine, but I just would like to double-check if there's some easier way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not overly familiar with the `UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY` function, but using it in a UNION query, in conjunction with the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function, will give you the result you desire:

```
WITH
    temp AS
    (
    SELECT log_message, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY log_message) rn
    FROM logs_table
    WHERE UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY(log_message, 'Unable to make thread 19043 a realtime process') > 80
    UNION
    SELECT log_message, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY log_message) rn
    FROM logs_table
    WHERE UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY(log_message, 'FEED_XYZ Secondary Instrument Lines not configured') > 80
    )
SELECT log_message
FROM temp
WHERE rn = 1
;
```

Result (screenshot from test DB at [apex.oracle.com](https://apex.oracle.com/)):

[image]

If you just need any value from each group (as opposed to the "first" value in each sorted group), you could use `ROWNUM` criteria instead of the `ROW_NUMBER` functions, which would return a similar result:

```
WITH
    temp AS
    (
    SELECT log_message
    FROM logs_table
    WHERE UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY(log_message, 'Unable to make thread 19043 a realtime process') > 80
      AND ROWNUM = 1
    UNION
    SELECT log_message
    FROM logs_table
    WHERE UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY(log_message, 'FEED_XYZ Secondary Instrument Lines not configured') > 80
      AND ROWNUM = 1
    )
SELECT log_message
FROM temp
;
```

However, unless there is a specific reason why you need to use `UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY`, there's a chance you may be falling victim to the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You could achieve identical results by replacing the two individual WHERE-clause lines (in either query above) with these:

```
WHERE log_message LIKE 'Unable to make thread %'
WHERE log_message LIKE 'FEED\_%' ESCAPE '\'
```

Or these (e.g. if there is a need for more fine-grained filtering):

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(log_message, 'Unable\sto\smake\sthread\s\d+\sa\srealtime\sprocess')
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(log_message, 'FEED_[A-Z]{3}\sSecondary\sInstrument\sLines\snot\sconfigured')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer, but the point here is: I want to have a generic SQL that will return just the unique "log_message" from "logs_table". The example was just to illustrate. I ended up creating a pipelined function (sorry for the extra tables, but this was a final solution to my environment):

```
function get_alert_messages return rl_alert_info_table pipelined as
  /*
    This function returns the distinct error messages using the algorithm Jaro Winkler to get rid
    of slightly different strings.
    More info: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/u_match.htm
    Example of use:
    select * from table(rl.get_alert_messages())
  */
  cursor logs_cur is select distinct r.customer_id, r.report_id, r.server_id, r.name as report_name, li.message
                       from reports r, logs l, logs_info li
                      where r.dateandtime > to_timestamp(to_char(current_timestamp,'DD-MON-YYYY')||' 01:00:00') and -- beginning of the day
                              r.report_id = l.report_id and 
                              li.log_id = l.log_id and
                              li.type_id = 4 and
                              li.timedetail > to_timestamp(to_char(current_timestamp,'DD-MON-YYYY')||' 01:00:00') 
                      order by r.customer_id, r.report_id, li.message; -- the order by is important here.
  l_message logs_cur%rowtype;
  l_last_msg logs_info.message%type;
begin
  begin
  open logs_cur;
  l_last_msg := ''; -- this variable stores the message from the previous row.
  loop 
    fetch logs_cur into l_message;
    exit when logs_cur%notfound;
      if utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(l_last_msg,l_message.message) < 85 then -- if the level of similarity is less than 85%
        pipe row(rl_alert_info(l_message.customer_id,
                              l_message.server_id,
                              l_message.report_name,
                              l_message.message));
     end if;
      l_last_msg := l_message.message;
  end loop;
  close logs_cur;
  exception
    when others then 
      close logs_cur;
      raise;
  end;
  return;
end get_alert_messages;
```